# How can I check if a string contains two other strings

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a variable which holds exception messages. How can I check if the exception message text is something like this:

```
 var ex.message = "Cannot open server 'abcd' requested by the login";
```

Note that the server name could be any length?

Comment: Define *something like this*. You mean the text is all the same save the `'abcd'` part? What would the other candidate strings that should fail look like? Do any of the others start with `"Cannot open server"`? Look at the `String` class on MSDN, there's a bunch of methods you could use, `Contains`, `StartsWith`, `IndexOf`, or you could use a regex, for example: `Cannot open server '(.*)' requested by the login`, which lets you grab the sever name too.

Comment: As someone who has asked almost 1000 questions on SO, I would expect you to know by now that a post like this would get heavily downvoted.

Comment: Its better to determine from Exception Type rather than from Exception Message.

Comment: Exception messages are also localised ...

Comment: You are probably better off checking the exception type (`Sqlexception`) and looking at the other useful properties it comes with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ex.message.Contains("Cannot open server") && ex.message.Contains("requested by the login")
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using the exception message to determine what has gone wrong. Instead catch the relevant exception type and deal with it in there. For example you likely wnat to use [`SqlException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
try
{
    ConnectToDatabase();
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    //Now we know a SQL exception has occurred, perhaps check the Number property?
    if(ex.Number == 18456) 
    {
        //Login failed
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //General exception handling goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much David. I was not aware the exeption even had a number

Comment: @Alan `Exception` doesn't but `SqlException` does.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a regular expression

```
var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(exceptionMessage, "Cannot open server '[^']+' requested by the login");
```

Answer (score 1):

With `string.Contains("string")`.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
ex.message.StartsWith("Cannot open server") && ex.message.EndsWith("requested by the login")
```

You can also check what goes in the middle if you already know the server name.

Why not do it better and define your own custom exception. e.g. `ServerConnectionFailedException`

Answer (score 1):

A bit exotic solution (via *extesnion methods*):

```
  public static class Strings {
    public static Boolean ContainsAll(this String source, params String[] toFind) {
      if (null == toFind)
        return true; // or throw an exception
      else if (toFind.Length <= 0)
        return true;

      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        return false;

      foreach (var item in toFind)
        if (!source.Contains(item))
          return false;

      return true;
    }
  }

  ...

  var ex.message = "Cannot open server 'abcd' requested by the login";

  if (ex.message.ContainsAll("Cannot open server", "requested by the login")) {
    ...
  }
```